# cant install angular-toastr with bower

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bower-install, toastr

I am trying to install angular-toastr with

> bower install angular-toastr

. I could see the below error. Is is the problem with the repo?

```
    bower not-cached    https://github.com/johnpapa/toastr-bower.git#*
    bower resolve       https://github.com/johnpapa/toastr-bower.git#*
    bower checkout      toastr#2.1.3
    bower ECMDERR       Failed to execute "git clone https://github.com/johnpapa/toastr-bower.git -b 2.1.3 --progress . -   -depth 1", exit code of #128 Cloning into '.'... remote: Counting objects: 12, done. remote: Compressing objects:remote: Compressing objects: 100% (12/12), done.         remote: Total 12 (delta2), reused 1 (delta 0),pack-reused 0         Checking connectivity... done. Note: checking out 'd6fef68471aa1836bc44ba1a41a90a96548b784f'.  You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental changes and commit them,      and you can discard any commits you make in this state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.  If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:    git checkout -b <new-branch-name>  error: unable to create file toastr.js: Permission denied error: unable to create file toastr.min.js: Permission denied fatal: unable to checkout working tree warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed. You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status' and retry the checkout with 'git checkout -f HEAD'
```

Comment: It worked fined for me. Not sure if it is the right repo to checkout This is the one:  resolve https://github.com/Foxandxss/angular-toastr.git#*

Comment: install `2.1.1` version stable  `bower install angular-toastr#2.1.1`

Comment: @hemanth, have you tried with that version?

Comment: @Sravan i tried 2.1.1 but still the same issue